# Ionicons not showing after npm installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix, ionicons

I installed [ionicons](http://ionicons.com/) using `npm install --save ionicons` so that my `package.json` updated to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Next, I added the following in my `/resources/assets/sass/app.scss`:

```
// Ionicons
@import "node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons";
```

After successfully running `npm run dev`, I ended up with

```
/public
    /css
        app.css
    /fonts
        /vendor
            /ionicons
                /dist
                    ionicons.eot
                    ionicons.svg
                    ionicons.ttf
                    ionicons.woff
                    ionicons.woff2
```

With no errors in the browser console, not a *single* ionicon (e.g. `<i class="icon ion-home"></i>`) is showing. I inspected `public/css/app.css`, and found that it references ionic fonts like so: `/fonts/vendor/ionicons/dist/ionicons`, which seems to comply with the folder structure above.

I tried adjusting `@import`, changing `url(...)` refrences in `app.css`, moving fonts directory - no luck. Lastly, I tried to reference ionicons through a CDN, and it worked like charm.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Try clearing your cache and also open the browser console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Sandeesh It's not a caching issue; like I said, it works with CDN, and there's no errors in console probably b/c css paths are messed up or some files are missing. But there's no 404s

Comment: i meant the app.css might be cached locally. Using the cdn would act as a different resource. You can try to force refresh the cache with ctrl + f5 if you're on chrome. Also inspecting the styles will give you relative links to the fonts inside the css. You can verify if they're pointing correctly by clicking on the font links in the style tab.

Comment: For test, add this in your css file `:not(i) { font: 'Arial'}` and clear any custom font you applied. then, check if icons appear or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the docs for the wrong version of ionicons:

- v2.0.0 [ionicons.com](http://ionicons.com/)
- v3.0.0 [ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/)

If you install ionicons with [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionicons) as I did, you'll get the latest version; if you clone them from their [github repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons), you'll get v2.0.0. It turns out that in v3.0.0, many icon classes were removed/changed, hence I couldn't see `<i class="icon ion-home"></i>`, what a waste of time!

Answer (score 1):

Paste these two lines right before your  tag:

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Uninstall ionicon from your depencency:
npm uninstall ionicons

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this issue. This is what fixed it for me :slight_smile:

```
npm uninstall ionicons

npm install ionicons
```

Answer (score 0):

when you install the package
add this command : ng add @ionic/angular

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Now the Ionicons has been updated to v4.x. (Answer written at 2019-06-24)

Try like this:

1. Before import the scss after install, set the value of `$ionicons-font-path`:

   ```
   $ionicons-font-path: "~ionicons/dist/fonts";
   @import '~ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons.scss';
   ```
2. When use the icon tag, write in `ion-icon` tag:

   ```
   <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
   ```